# Pushing from existing local branch to new online repository

Tags: git, gitlab, git-flow

Basically what we have is `master` and `testing-stage` in our online repository.

I am currently connected to `testing-stage` and updated with my local. Now, the testing-stage has been merged with `master`.

Then what happened is that the `testing-stage` has been deleted manually on gitLab's website then a new repo was created and it was named `test`, it is identically to master which finished merging like mentioned above. Now I have done some changes and would like to checkout and push to `test`, but my current local repository is listening to the previous `testing-stage` which is now deleted. What is the best thing that I may do?

Answer (score 2):

Given I understood your problem correctly...

Running `git remote -v` will allow you to see your remote URLs.

What you can do is remove the old remote URL pointing to the old repository:

```
git remote rm remote_name
```

I suspect the name will be `origin`.

Then you can add a new remote pointing to the new repository:

```
git remote add origin url_to_new_repository
```

You can also just add a new remote URL without removing the old one, in which case you will have two different remote URLs.

Answer (score 1):

I would do like that:

1. Clone `test` repository to have it locally
2. Look at the modified files in `testing-stage` with `git status`
3. Copy/paste all these modified files to the folder project of `test` repository
4. Push the modification to remote `test` repository

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to cherry-pick your changes from your current branch to the master branch from test. That is:

- change the remote URL:

  ```
  git remote rename origin oldorigin
  git remote add origin $test_url
  ```
- give a new name to your current branch:

  ```
  git checkout -b mybranch
  ```
- switch to the master branch and pull:

  ```
  git checkout master
  git pull -u origin master:master
  ```

  Now the local master branch should be synchronized with the master branch from the test repository.
- cherry-pick your changes. For each of your new commits:

  ```
  git log mybranch # find id of your commit
  git cherry-pick $commit_id
  ```
- finally, push to test's master

  ```
  git push
  ```